# Linux not freeing the file buffer when we execute rm or > (redirection) operator

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a router with *embedded-linux*, kernel version **2.4.22**. I know its very old version but I have to deal with it. The following is `free` command output on the box,

> [8300002902-3] Debug> free
>
> ```
>              total         used         free       shared      buffers
>   Mem:       128104       123928         4176            0         2164
>  Swap:            0            0            0
> Total:       128104       123928         4176
> ```

Now my problem is that whenever it execute some commands and redirects its output to some file using the `>` operator the buffer size is increased by **4KB** and even if I remove the same file using `rm -rf` the buffer again increase by **4KB**. due to this when my buffer size reaches at near **5.3MB** of size the OOM problem occurs as you can see that I only have 128MB RAM available. I think the kernel is not reclaiming the buffer space. Please tell me what can be done to get rid of this problem. I have researched the setting **drop_caches** value in the `/proc/sys/vm` but this command is not available at my kernel version.

Here is the proc/meminfo dump may be it can help.

[8300002902-3] Debug> cat /proc/meminfo

```
         total:    used:    free:  shared: buffers:  cached:
Mem:  131178496 126545920  4632576        0  2211840 54927360
Swap:        0        0        0
MemTotal:       128104 kB
MemFree:          4524 kB
MemShared:           0 kB
Buffers:          2160 kB
Cached:          53640 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:          66628 kB
Inactive:        36692 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:       128104 kB
LowFree:          4524 kB
SwapTotal:           0 kB
SwapFree:            0 kB
```

Comment: Is this `Linux` or `uClinux`?  The latter can have difficulty reclaiming memory since it's built to work on systems without an MMU to flexibly remap available space and give processes their own private address space.

Comment: Can you also dump the out put of /proc/meminfo

Comment: @AhmedMasud Please see the proc/meminfo dump that u requested and I am using Linux only

Comment: what happens to buffers after you run `sync` ?

Comment: Nothing happen when i exceute the sync command...the buffer size remains the same...@AhmedMasud

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518433/how-to-stop-page-cache-for-disk-i-o-in-my-linux-system

Comment: Is the file still open in some process?  If so `rm` will only prevent it being newly opened, it will not close open file handles or their ability to access the file data, so presumably would not free buffers either.

Comment: To follow on @ChrisStratton , can you do `lsof` to see what else might be going on?

Comment: Would you give a specific example of a command you are running and redirecting standard output using the > operator?  Another process holding onto a file descriptor of the file is the most plausible explanation.